# Upgrading project from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to upgrade my project to Visual Studio 2013. For upgrading I simply opened the project with Visual Studio 2013. But no conversion dialog was shown and when the project is opened it has ***Visual Studio 2012*** written in brackets (See snapshot):

[image]

What is the meaning of Visual Studio 2012 written in brackets. And is there anyway to convert this project to Visual Studio 2013 manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to this issue. The parenthesis means that VS 2013 will use toolset of VS 2012 because the project hasn't been upgraded to VS 2013.

And to convert c++ project there is a 'Update C++ Project' in the Project menu.